# Trying to iterate over records from CsvHelper throws ConfigurationException error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, automapper, ienumerable, csvhelper

I'm trying to iterate through a .csv file to output on the console. I am using CsvHelper and I followed the guides to the T but whenever I try to iterate through the IEnumerable that I get from the GetRecords() method, a ConfigurationException comes up.

Here is the code that I am using

```
using (var reader_ans = new StreamReader("scriptlists/prac_iden_ans.csv"))
using (var csv_ans = new CsvReader(reader_ans))
{
    var ans = csv_ans.GetRecords<string>();

    foreach (string item in ans)
    {
        Debug.Log(item);
    }
}
```

It's weird because this is exactly what's in the documentation and multiple websites.

The error that comes up is this:

```
ConfigurationException: Types that inherit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped. Did you accidentally call GetRecord or WriteRecord which acts on a single record instead of calling GetRecords or WriteRecords which acts on a list of records?
```

I was wondering if it's some silly thing that I'm missing because I am pretty new to C#. I am also coding this in Unity3D so could that maybe be part of the problem?

I've tried using the .ToList() method as well on the very first line to no avail.

---

Edit1:

After trying to create a custom class, I have run into another error, this time from the compiler before I can even run the code.

In essence, in this snippet of code:

```
foreach (string item in ans)
            {
                Debug.Log(item);
            }
```

the foreach gets highlighted and it displays an error saying "Cannot convert type 'instructions.ScriptsList' to 'string'". My file is named "instructions.cs".

Some extra information as well that might be the problem:

1) I am writing this piece of code within an IEnumerator, but I don't think that should be a problem as I do have other "foreach" lines in there. Unless CsvHelper uses certain code that would not work while within an IEnumerator?

2) My .csv files were created in excel and they do have headers. It is actually just multiple columns of "Yes" and "No"s. Would creating it in Excel and saving it as .csv (Comma Delimited) have affected how it's being read by CsvHelper?

3) Does it matter that the class is written above this function? (I know this is kind of basic but I'm pretty new to C# and I've noticed that in a lot of the documentation the class is usually written below the function)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You need a class of Foo as the [example](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/) points out

Comment: Is you first column numeric?  The csvHelper is using the Jet Engine which is the driver for Excel and Access.  The Jet engine assumes the first column when numeric to be the Row Number not column data.  So then all the other columns get moved to an index one lower than what you expect.  It is the same issue with using General Format in Excel which attempts to guess data type and often changes numbers to dates and dates to numbers.  Microsoft tried to add intelligence into their software which often makes mistakes.

Comment: `Debug.Log()` is looking for a string and you are giving it an `instructions.ScriptsList` object.

Comment: @DavidSpecht Debug.Log takes an `object` and does a ToString's on it. Does not matter what you feed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you received refers to it being unable to populate with the given configuration.

You want to give `GetRecords<>` a class or struct which it will populate with the values from each row in your `.csv`. Your script probably failed due to it trying to populate a row into the `string` type and failed.

Example solution, given your `.csv` looks similar to this:

Your `prac_iden_ans.csv` file:

```
Path
C:/example/path/one
C:/example/path/two
```

Your `.cs` C# script file:

```cs
void YourFunction() {

    using (var reader_ans = new StreamReader("scriptlists/prac_iden_ans.csv"))
    using (var csv_ans = new CsvReader(reader_ans))
    {
        var ans = csv_ans.GetRecords<ScriptsList>();

        foreach (ScriptsList item in ans)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.Path);
        }
    }

}

class ScriptsList {
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

---

However, if your `.csv` file is missing a header row (i.e. the first row specifying what each column represents) you can configure `CsvReader` to not expect one. However then you have to tell the `CsvReader` which columns to map to which properties in a different way. One way is the `IndexAttribute`. Example:

Your `prac_iden_ans.csv` file:

```
C:/example/path/one
C:/example/path/two
```

Your `.cs` C# script file:

```cs
void YourFunction() {

    using (var reader_ans = new StreamReader("scriptlists/prac_iden_ans.csv"))
    using (var csv_ans = new CsvReader(reader_ans))
    {
        csv_ans.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        var ans = csv_ans.GetRecords<ScriptsList>();

        foreach (ScriptsList item in ans)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.Path);
        }
    }

}

class ScriptsList {
    [Index(0)]
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

---

But if your just reading each line in the file row by row I would instead recommend just using a [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8), [`File.OpenRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread?view=netframework-4.8), or simply [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_). Example:

Your `prac_iden_ans.csv` file:

```
C:/example/path/one
C:/example/path/two
```

Your `.cs` C# script file:

```cs
string[] ans = File.ReadAllLines("scriptlists/prac_iden_ans.csv");

foreach (string item in ans)
{
    Debug.Log(item);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use your third suggestion as I do have multiple columns in the .csv file, though it is a good one for future reference.
My .csv does have a header. I just tried creating a custom class, but it seems like another problem cropped up. I will show it in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

For your updated question:

1. It was a typo on my part. Forgot to change the `foreach` item variable from `string` to `ScriptsList`. I've updated my answer. Your snippet should be:

```cs
foreach (ScriptsPath item in ans)
{
    Debug.Log(item);
}
```

2. No. There are no differences. Only thing to look out for is sometimes a `.csv` is formatted with semicolon `;` instead of comma `,` as separator. But `.csv` is one of the most basic formats out there
3. No. It's a common convention to write `class`, `struct` and `enum`'s at the bottom of the file and below the class if it occupies the same file/example. It is part of the C# syntax and C# compilers to **not** require a specific location of type definitions. This is different compared to the code you write in methods that are top-to-bottom while type definitions follow a broader tree-like structure.

   The code flow you write in C# is just one part of the C# full syntax. In my opinion the power in C# comes in the rest of its syntax, with stuff like namespaces, properties, enumerator methods, accessibility modifiers, etc.

Comment: Oh yes that did it. Thank you for all your help and advice! (: